# Doubt with test of condensation Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Good night, i have a serious problem with the proof of this test.

I search the proof in Google but i dont understand some items.

The theorem with the proof:

[image: Test Condensation Cauchy]

Well, i dont understand this part:

$n>2^{k-1}$ and $n<2^{k-1}$

Why that is true? Because he consider that inequality? That is my doubt, please help!

Comment: If $n<2^k-1$, then \*blah blah blah\*, else you would have $n>2^{k-1}$, so \*blah blah blah\* to put this shortly.  Indeed, I'm unsure what you don't understand, since he's just making statements.

Comment: What on earth is your title trying to say?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Why he take that inequality? and because that is true? (The inqueality)

Comment: He takes the inequality... because he wants to take that inequality.  Its like asking "why can't $\epsilon$ be twice as large?" in a $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proof of a limit.  It could be if you wanted, but we recommend doing it this way.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to understand how the author grouped the terms.  Maybe that should be a tad more insightful.  I will say though, if you know of the integral test, then you can just note that:$$\sum f(n)\longrightarrow\int f(x)\ dx\stackrel{x=2^u}\longrightarrow\int2^uf(2^u)\ln(2)\ du\longrightarrow\sum2^nf(2^n)$$where I threw away constants not needed for the convergence check.